# RagDoll in AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I want to create a RagDoll body in andEngine which can run and jump over different jumpObjects. Can any one give a nice tutorial on how to create RagDoll body and how to move it, like jump and running.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think anyone will give you a "nice" tutorial. What research have you done so far yourself?

Comment: I am reading Box2d manual.

Comment: I know about the joints and bodies, but i want to know how to move different parts of body when the object is running or the object makes a jump.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mis concept all the thing. For developing contra like character you have to create a single body either box or circle that does not matter. For providing jump you have to give impulse to that single body. And body contains the sequence of sprite to make all the effect like walking, jumping etc. If does not require then you do not need to create a joints between multiple bodies.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But my problem is that when body collide with walking track, joints start movement and body can't stand straight. i am taking help from this site.. http://code.google.com/p/andengine-ragdoll/source/browse/trunk/src/obg1/RagDoll/RagDollGame.java

Comment: That's because ragdoll is exactly what the name says. It is good at being tossed around, making it move is very hard. If you think you can make it work like this, try playing this game for a while: http://www.foddy.net/Athletics.html and then think again. You could just animate some sprites and when you need the character to fall, simply read the sprites' coordinates and attach a ragdoll in the same posture and velocity.

Comment: I am completely agree with JohnEye. You need to rethink about that one.